# Keeping 3 rows for particular values in column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`, which has the column `months_to_maturity` and has multiple rows associated with a `months_to_maturity` of 1,2, etc. each. I am trying to keep only the first 3 rows associated with a particular `months_to_maturity` value. For example, for `months_to_maturity = 1` I would like to have only 3 associated rows and for `months_to_maturity = 2`, another 3 rows and so on. I try to do this using the code below, but get the error `IndexError: index 21836 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4412` and hence am wondering if there is a better way to do this. `pairwise` gives the current and next row of the dataframe. The values of `months_to_maturity` are sorted.

```
count = 0
for (i1, row1), (i2,row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
    if row1.months_to_maturity == row2.months_to_maturity:
        count = count + 1
        if count == 3:
            df.drop(df.index[i1])
            df = df.reset_index()        
    elif row1.months_to_maturity != row2.months_to_maturity:
        count = 0
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.groupby('months_to_maturity').head(3)
```